# Prevent BsDateRangePicker showing future months | angular8

Tags: angular, datepicker, ngx-bootstrap

In my BsDaterange picker, I want to achieve future dates disabled,

although I am doing it correctly, when I click the current day it jumps into the future month, which is not a good practice,

To refactor:- please click on today `current Date`, it should not jump to a future month,

```
<input type="text"
           placeholder="Daterangepicker"
           class="form-control"
           bsDaterangepicker
           [bsConfig]="{ showPreviousMonth: true }"
           [maxDate]="maxDate"   
           >
```

.ts

```
maxDate = new Date();
```

Working Demo -- Stackblitz

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cxy5xw?file=app%2Fshow-previous-month.html

Comment: When I open the calendar, I see January and February. If I click 2/2 (today), the first card is February and the second is March.

Do you want to leave January and February open by clicking 2/2 (today)?

Comment: Practicallly, Yess Max Ferreira ,

Answer (score 0):

I think, feature, that you want to, can be available very soon via [this PR](https://github.com/valor-software/ngx-bootstrap/pull/6058)